# How to remove Android/PUP.Adware.SnowFox.a Adware?

Tags: malware

There is a hidden adware installed in my android , which slides(Pops) a full screen  add on the screen by surprise when operating the touch screen and immediately gets a click and redirects to browser or google play store and begs to install a nonsense app.

I installed Malware bytes and it has detected a adware,

[image: adware]

And when i hit uninstall , i get uninstall successful but there it again,

I installed root explorer and browsed to the location and tried to delete it and my OS says it is read only.

Is there any other meth0d to remove the adware.?

Android version 5.1.1
kernel version 3.10.49-perf-g2808008-00335-gacd81a9ccadmin@BUILD19 #1

Comment: I think factory resetting is the next step here...

Comment: @timoschwarzer factory reset doesn't touch `/system`. Instead, one neads to remount `/system` read-write: use `adb shell` to get a shell prompt, then `su` and `mount -o remount,rw /system` and `rm /system/app/SnapdragonCamera/SnapdragonCamera.apk`, and at last a reboot. Alternatively, use one of the [system app uninstallers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_456) available :)

Comment: @lzzy you are right. For some reason I didn't notice/saw the picture in the question. 

Comment: The device is rooted?

Comment: @MarkYisri It is not rooted .

Comment: No wonder Root Explorer shows read-only then.